# C# reading an Excel work book, OLEDB or Excel Interop?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net, oledb, excel-interop

I need to read an Excel work book with 2 sheet which have more than 60,000 records. The application is an ASP.Net application so the performance matters.

Which approach should I take? Should I do it using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel or should I do it using OLEDB in ADO.Net?

What is the best approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the book into two worksheet files, convert them to CSV (comma-separated value) form, and process them as text.

I think that would be the best approach perfomance-wise, if you only need to read the data and do not care about formatting, merged cells, formulae etc.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your advice, but the reading process should be an automated one. The user only needed to upload the work book. Rest have to be done by the system.

Comment: Hmm is it a one-time thing, or there would be several such Excel books?

Comment: One time for each operation. The problem is that I cannot make user to go for extra stems. It has to be automated.

Answer (score 0):

I used always OLEDB in ADO.Net for it.

What the best aproach is, I don't know. But the easiest is like Kaerber says, to read it as 2 `.csv` files.
Then you can read it like you read a `.txt` file without 'fancy' libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Use OLEDB for querying (reading) and Interop when modifying Excel.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using:

gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet

or the free alternative:

http://npoi.codeplex.com/